# Best way to describe - between two numbers

Tags: excel

I am placing text in a cell on a spreadsheet that represents a value from a starting value of 1 and an ending value of 10. This is not going to be used in a formula its for representing the in-between numbers in ONE cell on a spreadsheet.

Whats the BEST way to express this in a simple text way?

- a) 1 - 10
- b) 1 to 10
- c) 1 .. 10
- d) 1 ... 10
- e) >0 <11

These come to mind,  but perhaps there is a more correct way that I am missing?

Comment: is it for the user or for excel? for the user it depends on the local culture.

Comment: If it is to guide a user about a value to be entered into a cell then you should also consider adding data validation to that cell. If it is to explain a result that appears in a cell you might want to consider adding a comment to the cell.

Comment: I got down-voted because this was originally posted to JavaScript.  I did that because I did not have enough votes to post it to google sheets tag. Sorry about that....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct mathematical expression would be 1 ... 10 or 1 <= x <= 10 but the second expression is not easy to understand.

1 - 10 is in common usage but could be misunderstood as 1 subtract 10.

If this is for 'the general public' then "Between 1 and 10" would make sense.